# what will happen to a table having foreign key when the table refrencing to it is dropped

Tags: sql, oracle

suppose I have a table:

`table1 (column1,column2,column3,...)primary key (column1, column2));`

And I also have another table:

`table2 (column1,column2,column3,...) foreign key (column1, column2) references table1 on delete cascade`

Now when I drop `table1`, I can still see the value of `column1` and `column2` in my `table2`. I want to know why `column1` and `column2` are still there after dropping `table1` and what happened to the `foreign key (column1, column2)`.?

And is there SQL query to check this foreign key after `table1` is dropped.

Comment: As far as I know, Oracle won't let you drop a table if there's a foreign key refering to it.

Comment: @RobertKock we can drop it using `drop table courses cascade constraints`

Comment: Didn't think of that. In your case, the foreign key is removed but the column values remain unchanged. In other words, it removes the forein key itself, not the columns that compose the foreign key.

Comment: @RobertKock is there any sql query to check this foreign key?

Comment: What do you mean with 'check the foreign key'?

Comment: @RobertKock I mean is there a query through which we can get the output of list of foreign key of a particular table.

Comment: Check out `SELECT * FROM user_constraints WHERE constraint_type = 'R'`

Comment: You can query for the foreign key but it won't be there. When you drop the primary key using "cascade constraints", the foreign key constraint is also dropped (but the columns remain as they're part of the table).

Comment: ORA-02449: unique/primary keys in table referenced by foreign keys